# Why (N+1)sec's mDP Implementation does not check whether all the XORED received $z$ values are 0

Tags: key-exchange, key-generation

In the original [mDP](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/2010_africacryptB.pdf) protocol once all $z$ values received from each participant the following calculation is being done:

> If either $XOR(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) = 0 $ or received invalid Signature then abort the the key computation.
>   Else $z'_{j,j+1} = XOR(z'_{j_j-1},z'_{j})$
>
> And the final Key will be: $k_i=H_g(z'_{1,2},\ldots,z'_{n,1},sid_i)$

But on the approach used (N+1)sec of the algorithm above the check  $XOR(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) = 0$ is not performed thus I want to ask  why in (N+1)sec this check is omitted?

Also I attempted to implement the key agreement, thus I want to ask in what conditions/requirements do I need so I can omit the check $XOR(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) = 0$ as well?